# Norm on a integral

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E= C([a,b])=\{f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; f \ \text{is continuous} \}$ and $|| \quad||_1: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $$||f||_1=\int_a^b|f(x)|dx.$$

Show that there is no $c>0$ for which $$\mathop{max}_{x \in [a,b]} f(x)<c||f||_1.$$

I tried to do some examples first, but i think that there is some information missing in the question, if we use $f(x)=a$, $a$ is some constant, we can find an c. Any tips on how to solve it?

Comment: Well, as you pointed out, there is a counterexample. You need to find the missing information for us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

In other words, it says that the quantity
$$
\frac{\max_{x\in [a, b]} f(x)}{||f||_{1}}
$$
is unbounded. To make this *large*, imagine the situation where $||f||_{1}$ is fixed but $\max_{x\in [a, b]}f(x)$ being larger. How about a function that looks like a **spike**? More precisely, consider a triangle-like function where the area is fixed but the graph gets steeper and steeper.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose WLOG that $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Take $(f_n)_{n\geq 2}$ defined by $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&x\in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]\\ nx+1-n&x\in (1-\frac{1}{n},1].\end{cases}
$$
Then, $f_n\to 0$ in $(E,\|\cdot \|_1)$. Now, suppose that there is $c>0$ s.t. for all $f\in E$, $$\max_{[a,b]}|f|\leq c\|f\|_1.$$

In particular, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $$1=|f_n(1)|\leq \max_{[a,b]}|f_n|\leq c\|f_n\|_1\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0,$$
which is a contradiction. Therefore, such $c>0$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, i get it, but i still have a doubt: If we take a simple continuous function like $f(x)=x$ in $[0,1]$, we have $\mathop{max}_{x\ in [0,1]}=1$ and $\int_a^b x dx=1/2$, why can't we just choose $c\geq 2$?

Comment: Your statement should be : there is $c>0$ s.t. for all $f\in E$ $$\max_{[a,b]}|f|\leq c\|f\|_1.$$ Of course, for some $f\in E$, there is $c>0$ s.t. $\max_{[a,b]}|f|\leq c\|f\|_1$. You even have, $$\forall f\in E, \exists c>0: \max_{[a,b]}|f|\leq c\|f\|_1.$$ @Lucascantu